# NitroShare and UFW firewall

Tags: ufw, nitroshare

I have installed NitroShare 0.3.1* on Ubuntu 18.10 and 0.3.4 on Windows 7. I can transfer files in either direction with UFW firewall off, but not with it on. I assumed that I needed to add some rules to UFW and tried this for the Transfer port

[image]

and something similar for the broadcast port 40816. The result is this

[image]

This works - but is it correct? I don't want to take any risks.

---

*The standard version 0.3.3 has a bug, it isn't related to security, it just stops the transfer.

Comment: If it works then what is or are your fear(s), and what bug?

Comment: when the firewall is up you could allow all incoming connections from the win 7 pc with `sudo ufw allow from <win7 ip>`

Comment: @ptetteh227, That looks better than what I have on my Linux machine, as I think my rules would allow links from any other WiFi connection if I was in public. What would I replace <win7> with? Is it the IP address of the Windows machine, and if so how would I find it out?

Comment: its a bit secure but it assumes the windows machine always gets the same ip when connected to the router. replace <win7 ip> with the windows 7 ip address. you can find it from the Windows command prompt by typing `ipconfig` or following the tutorial here https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/15291/windows-find-pc-ip-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[An ArchLinux page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uncomplicated_Firewall) says:

> **Basic configuration**
>
> A very simplistic configuration which will deny all by default, allow
> any protocol from inside a 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.255 LAN, and allow
> incoming Deluge and rate limited SSH traffic from anywhere:
>
> ufw default deny
>
> ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24
>
> ufw allow Deluge
>
> ufw limit SSH

So I picked out

```
# ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24
```

which I think should allow connections between computers within my LAN only. I'll now have to work out how to do this on the Windows computer.